# How to save multiple values with same meta_key, each value linked to another tag id

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, user-meta

Let´s say a user signs up to multiple memberships, each on a different date.

User signs up to:

- Membership A on 05.03.2021
- Membership B on 17.05.2021
- Membership C on 29.07.2021

I would like the dates for that user to be saved with the same meta_key.
Each saved value/date should be linked to the specific membership, so that I can run a check and get the date when the user signed up for a specific membership.

I have the following so far:

```php
$parameters = array(
    'member_id' => $user_id,
    'membership' => array (
        array (
        'tags'      =>  $tags,
        'datetime'  =>  time(),     
        )
        )
);

 add_user_meta( $user_id, 'membership', $parameters );
```

I would want to have the result for a user be something like:

```
membership:

[0]
    Tag: Membership A
    Date: 05.03.2021
[1]
    Tag: Membership B
    Date: 17.05.2021
[2]
    Tag: Membership C
    Date: 29.07.2021
```

In the `var_dump` it would look something like, where the number of sub-arrays for "membership" will be different per user, depending on the number of memberships they have assigned to them.

```
array(2) {
  ["member_id"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["memberships"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["membership"]=>
      string(5) "membership A"
      ["datetime"]=>
      int(1616239233)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["membership"]=>
      string(5) "membership B "
      ["datetime"]=>
      int(1616239233)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["membership"]=>
      string(5) "membership C"
      ["datetime"]=>
      int(1616239233)
    }
  }
}
```

I´m sure I am missing something, look forward to hearing your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Meta keys are not unique, you can have multiple key/value pairs with the same key. Although in this case, if you wanted to know when membership B started, how would you know if they all have the same key?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks. I thought something like this should be the result: $parameters = array( 'member_id' => $user_id, 'membership' => array ( array ( 'tags' => $tags, 'datetime' => time(), ) ) ); add_user_meta( $user_id, 'membership', $parameters ); I would want to have the result for a user be something like: membership: [0] - Tag: Membership A - Date: 05.03.2021 [1] - Tag: Membership B - Date: 17.05.2021 [2] - Tag: Membership C - Date: 29.07.2021 I´m sure I am missing something, look forward to hearing your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your response, or what the code that would produce that expected result would look like. I don't understand why you can't do what the docs say to do, `$results = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key', false ); foreach ( $results as $result ) { ....`

Comment: For example, you say this is what you want th `var_dump` to look like, but the `var_dump` or what? You never show what or how you are calling `var_dump` or where the value comes from

Comment: Also, if you only want the memberships, you should only store the memberships

Comment: @TomJNowell Hmm. I guess coding being new to me, makes it so that I seem to have a hard time explaining well what I want to achieve. So sorry for that.

Comment: A user can sign up to 1 or more memberships. I basically want to track the sign-up dates per membership. Once the combination membership name + sign-up date is saved, that (part of the) value should not change anymore.

Comment: When a user signs up for a membership, I can use user add_user_meta or update_user_meta to save/update two things in one meta_value for for one meta_key.
So, those 2 things are; the membership the user signs up for & the date when the signing up happens.

I can make it work, so that for each time a user signs up for a membership a new meta_value  record is created.

Comment: BUT, I thought it would be possible / cleaner (database bloat) to save / update one and the same meta_key/meta_value per user.

So each user has 1 meta_key/meta_value record where all his membership / date combinations are saved.

Comment: So, some users will have only 1 membership / sign-up date record saved.... Others might have 5 membership / sign-up date combinations, cause they have purchased 5 different memberships.

Comment: Because the user_id is available in the wp_usermeta table, my guess was you could get the meta_key > meta_value > data for a user. Then you would have the different membership+date combinations and could run some checks with that.

Again, perhaps / possibly / probably I am overseeing / overcomplicating things.

Comment: Instead of 1 piece of meta that stores 5 memberships. Use 5 pieces of meta that store 1 membership each. Note that right now it's unclear what kind of answer you want, the only thing i can think of is if someone did all the work for you and gave you a copy paste example. Otherwise both myself and Parmar have demonstrated how to save user meta and how to retrieve it. If that did not answer your question then you're going to have to explain what is missing and what your question is

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, is that you don't know how to access values inside of arrays, but you have not said this, and that would be beginner level PHP, not WordPress

Comment: Again, I am new to this and learning by doing. Sure I am a beginner and probably having a hard time to explain - in the same expert language - what my issues are. No, I didn´t receive code from someone else...  that probably would be better :). But, I prefer to learn myself, but perhaps this is not the place for beginners to look for help. If so, i´m sorry, my bad. I do honestly want to thank you for your help and taking the time to reply to my questions, even though they were not clearly enough laid out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert_user_meta($user_id,'meta_key','meta_value');`

when you want to get that keys, you can get like `$keys = get_user_meta($user_id,'meta_key');`

in `$keys` variable you get an array of all keys.

Comment: Thanks. I´ve updated / edited my question, I still a bit in the dark :). If you have any further tips, great!

Answer (score 0):

You've made some fatal misunderstandings that are not supported by the documentation.

1. Meta keys are not unique
2. If you store something then retrieve it you will get what you originally stored
3. It's a good idea to store arrays and objects in meta

### Meta keys are not unique

You can have multiple post meta with the same name. When you call `add_user_meta` you are not updating data, you are adding additional data. Now there are 2 `membership` post metas. Call it again and there will be 3.

```php
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', 'test' );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', 'test' );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', 'test' );

$examples = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', false );
foreach ( $examples as $example ) {
    // there are 3 examples
}
```

### If you store something then retrieve it you will get what you originally stored

Why would it return just the memberships sub-array? If you store something, you get it back when you retrieve it, not a sub-part of it.

Use `get_user_meta` to retrieve what you stored.

### It's a good idea to store arrays and objects in meta

What if I want all users with a particular membership ID? It can't be done! You can't query inside that value. You can't query inside serialised objects/arrays.

Your `membership_id` should be... a user meta named `membership_id`, and each individual membership should be a separate meta.